# Disable HTML element based on the php variable value in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a php page home.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
include_once("app_header.php");
$disableCreate = 'true';    

//below code to show the home page template
$htmlrenderObj = Htmlrender::getObj();          
$template_path  = $htmlrenderObj->app_home_template_path."app_home.html";
$template       = $htmlrenderObj->return_file_content($template_path);
ob_end_flush(); 
include_once("app_footer.php");
?>
```

In this php page, I have a php variable `$disableCreate` and I'm using the preoperatory class HTMLrender to provide common methods to replace the content into html templates.
Now based on the `$disableCreate` variable I need to disable the Create hyperlink.

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
     <div id="menuId">
       <ul>        
       <li><a href="view.php" id="tab-visited"> <span>View</span></a></li>         
        <li><a href="create.php" <?php echo $disableCreate; ?>><span>Create</span></a></li>                                     
        <li><a href="search.php?default=1"> <span>Search</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="update.php"><span>Update</span></a></li>                               
        <li><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="help.php"><span>Help</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

But I'm getting compile time error.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Invalid character used in text string (<?php echo 
 $disableCreate; ?>>).
- Start tag (<a>) not closed.
```

How can I disable the anchor tag based on the php variable.

Comment: Which framework had Htmlrender come from? Or is this something you've created?

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" colspan="2">
     <div id="menuId">
       <ul>        
        <li><a href="view.php" id="tab-visited"> <span>View</span></a></li>         
        <li><a <?php if(!$disableCreate) { echo "href='create.php'" }; ?> ><span>Create</span></a></li>                                     
        <li><a href="search.php?default=1"> <span>Search</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="update.php"><span>Update</span></a></li>                               
        <li><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="help.php"><span>Help</span></a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

And then change

```
$disableCreate = 'true';
```

To

```
$disableCreate = true;
```

With this work you check the `$disableCreate` value with this condition `if(!$disableCreate)` and the decide to add the `href` or not

Comment: Hi Azibom, thanks for your reply. I have changed my code as you suggested. Still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

could you try to use this code:
$GLOBALS['disableCreate'] = true;

and then instead of variable in the view use $GLOBALS['disableCreate']

Would it work?

Comment: Hi Ivan, still I'm getting the same error and it is saying Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Start tag (<a>) not closed.
 - Start tag (<a>) not closed.